# Column's Sortable changed table's background color

Tags: java, html, jsp-tags, displaytag

I've a table which is:

```
<display:table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1"
        name="${xxx}" id="xxx"
        styleClass="black11" bgcolor="#b3b3b3" export="true"
```

and when I add sortable to one of a column,column's title background changes.

```
<display:column title="Company Name Company Id" sortable="true" sortProperty="companyName">
```

I mean: before adding sortable="true", background color was grey, after adding that it changes to kind of blue;
how can I stop that changing?

Comment: is this a hard question?

Answer (score 0):

You could define that in your CSS, what is the HTML that that piece of outputs?